Quarto modules or include partials with parameters
When I create a dashboard in shiny, I create multiple modules to keep my source code organized.
Now I am playing around with Quarto Dashboards (but the question also relates to other Quarto documents) and want to follow a similar approach.
That is, I want to have "modules" that I want to re-use.
For example, I might want to have a tabset card with one tab for a chart and the second tab for the data that is called multiple times with different parameters.
I know of Quarto Includes (eg {{< include partials/my_tabset.qmd >}}) but this only works for one level (eg I cannot include another partial in my_tabset.qmd when its in a nested folder) and does not allow me to pass arguments.
One potential solutions is to have a small R wrapper function that calls quarto render with parameters on the partials and includes the output in the parent document. But this feels a bit hacky and too complicated for the task.
Are there any other options here for me?
I am aware of Quarto Discussion #8735.
Example
main.qmd
---
title: "tester"
author: "Me Myself and I"
format: dashboard
---

```{r}
# small helper function
insert_module <- function(file, ...) {
  env <- environment()
  env$params <- list(...)
  content <- knitr::knit_child(file, quiet = TRUE, envir = env)
  cat(content, sep = "\n")
}
```


# mtcars

```{r, results="asis"}
insert_module("partials/my_tabset.qmd", data = mtcars)
```

# chickwts

```{r, results="asis"}
insert_module("partials/my_tabset.qmd", data = chickwts)
```


partials/my_tabset.qmd
---
params:
  data: mtcars
---

## Column {.tabset title="Insights"}
```{r}
#| title: plot
plot(params$data[[1]], params$data[[2]])
```

```{r}
#| title: data
params$data
```


